# separate an aggregated object in ns3

Tags: c++, ns-3

I need to separate an *Ipv4L3Protocol* object aggregated with a *Node* object. The *Node* object already installed with an InternetStackHelper which aggregates it automatically with the *Ipv4L3Protocol* object.

The Goal is that I need Aggregate another *Ipv4L3Protocol* object if I just can separate this old *Ipv4L3Protocol* object from the node. 
Is there a way in general that helps me separate an aggregated object.